# value not set when sequence focus in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i leave the text box in field ,jquery automatically focus next textbox of form,

but arrival text box not set the value and goes to next departure box field

my code id

```
     <form name="searchForm" method="get" action="searchresult.php" class="" id="searchForm" novalidate="novalidate">
     <div class="form-horizontal" style="padding:10px;">
     <div class="form-group ">
     <label for="destiny">Destination</label>
     <input type="text" name="location" autocomplete="off" class="form-control textinput" id="destiny" onblur="dateselect1()" onKeyup="log()" placeholder="Enter Destination">
     <div id="livesearch"></div></div> 
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6"><label for="start_stayPeriod" class="control-label">Arrival</label>

     <input type="text" class="form-control textinput date-picker" name="startdate" onblur="dateselect2()"  id="datepicker1"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" ></div>

    <div class="col-sm-1"></div><div class="form-group col-sm-7">
     <label for="enddate" class="control-label">Departure</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control textinput " name="enddate"  id="datepicker2"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" >   </div>
      <script>
      function dateselect1(){
      $("#datepicker1").focus();
       }
        function dateselect2(){
        $("#datepicker2").focus();
        }
       </script>
        <input class="button searchb" name="submit" onClick="return valid()"  type="submit" value="Search for hotel"/>
    </div></form>
```

Comment: Actually, where's the code that attempts to set the value of something in the above code..?

Comment: when destination text box is given the value and i leave the field ,on blur function focus on next( arrival field) box and i give the value ,again on blur focus function moves next but that arrival textbox value not set.

Comment: Your code is invalid. Look at `form` tag: where is closing tag? Extra opening `div` etc.

Comment: *"and i give the value"* - where is the code that attempts to do so above?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9WJ4L/ - perhaps it will help you explain what your problem is?

Comment: in this form,i try to sequence focus the next text box when current field it typed or select,i use the date picker in arrival and departure. the both date picker are works good, but when i click arrival date picker date ,that value not set and its move to next one.